# jquery-json with special/extended ascii/utf characters

Tags: jquery, json, html-encode

I have been using jquery-json for a while now and find it to be a very reliable extension.  However, I have just run into a little issue tht is making me wonder if I am not skating on thin ice.  Here is a piece of JSON that jquery-json came up with today

```
{"taqa1618Asava4382C":[{"d":"Vegetariana [6\" - £6.99]","c":"2","p":"6.99"}],"edited":1230}
```

I fed that into PHPs json_decode and it immediately threw a wobbly.  It does not like the £ character and I guess that is reasonable.  Is there something I can do at the jQuery/browser end to get round this issue? A spot of googling has not yielded anything useful.

Hmmm... strikes me that this may not be the brightest question I have asked on this forum but it is the end of a long working day.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? Are you in UTF-8?

Comment: Seems to run fine here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/5bt-rwt
Check your environment if it's running in UTF8. It's honestly a pain to do the first time but totally worth it. http://allseeing-i.com/How-to-setup-your-PHP-site-to-use-UTF8

Comment: I had issues with PHP not being able to read json.. I believe the problem was with the non-ASCII chars

Comment: Thanks.  I hadn't thought of it but I tried the PHP on writecodeonline so I guess it is an issue with my server.  I ran into this problem on my local WAMP installation, it might well be ok on the real thing.  However, are there any gotchas with using jquery-json to pump out data to PHP?  By and large I have been using it blindly thus far and getting away with it.

Comment: @DroidOS You would be better off including https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js in my opinion. You would use it with JSON.stringify(objorarray) which will use the browser's built-in JSON.stringify if available, else use the one defined in the script.

Comment: Thanks for the note re using the Douglas Crockford code.  I was aware of it but had started using jquery json a while ago and then just kept swimming